# Generic datastructures in C

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree, cots

I'm looking into creating a generic BST. Nothing fancy no COTS, but I'm trying to decide the best way to keep track of the type of the void*. Here's the interface for the nodes:

```
typedef struct
{
   void *data;
   struct TreeNode *left;
   struct TreeNode *right;  
} TreeNode;
```

However, when I write add/remove, I'll need to do comparisons, hence I'll need to keep track of the type of data that "data" is pointing to, right?

Basic idea is to have an enum Node_Type and a function compareTreeNodes that receives the two TreeNodes and the enum as a 3rd arg. This would allow the function to determine what to cast the void* to.

Any other/better thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume a single BST will have only one type of data in it. In that case I would make a encapsulating `struct` that contains a pointer to the root node and a pointer to a comparison function. The user of your BST would have to provide a suitable function at initialisation.

```
typedef struct {
    TreeNode *root;
    int (*compar)(const void *, const void *);
} Tree;
```

Btw, your first line should probably be `typedef struct TreeNode {`. You have a typdef'd anonymous `struct`, but refer to a non-existent tagged struct inside.
These two versions would work:

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
    void *data;
    struct TreeNode *left, *right;
} TreeNode;

typedef struct TreeNode TreeNode;
struct TreeNode {
    void *data;
    TreeNode *left, *right;
};
```

You cannot make self-referential anonymous `structs`.

Comment: That's a great idea. I already have an instantiation function - I'll just have it receive a comparison function now. This will help with what I was discussing in the 2nd answer below. I didn't want the caller/user to pass a comparator each time they called add/remove/search/whatever. Awesome!

Comment: My typedef is correct. If I didn't preprend struct to the internal pointers (left/right), I would have a compiler error.

Comment: My mistake slash okay. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 4):

> However, when I write add/remove, I'll need to do comparisons, hence I'll need to keep track of the type of data that "data" is pointing to, right?

Look at how `qsort()` solves this issue. It, too, needs to work on arbitrary data types. Basically, you delegate comparison to users, through a function pointer.

Comment: I thought about using a function ptr. In fact, I'm trying to think of a way to allow a user to simplify the use if it's a supported data type, say char*, int*, char*. If it's something else, a struct for example, then I will have an addToBST( BST*, comparator*) function.

Comment: I suppose the only savings is that if a user is always creating char* BST's, then it allows for a more intuitive call to add/remove/search without passing a 3rd arg such as strcmp. (where the 1st is the BST and the 2nd is the node to add/remove/search fo)